# Android: onInfoWindowClick in the maps does not perform the function setText

Tags: android

I have this code:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.section3, container, false);

// Get a handle to the Map Fragment
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment)).getMap();

test_fr.setText("test"); // work

map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(

new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        test_fr.setText("test2"); // did not work, why??
    }
});
```

Why the higher line setText method works in onInfoWindowClick not?

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why are you using a new instance of GoogleMap instead your object map inflated previously ?

Comment: You mean the line: new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() { ??
So I told Android Studio and the example I found on the internet

Comment: oupss i said a mistake :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not solve my problem. I tried to give a toast at a function OnInfoWindowClickListener and executes it properly - do not know why it does not work in function setText. 
I forgot to write that I use Fragments (SectionFragment) and the button (test_fr) is in a different Fragmen. Just why it works on a higher line in the function OnInfoWindowClickListener unfortunately not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so sorry for the delay but i was really busy. So you get a `OnInfoWindowClickListener` but in the code above, there is no marker with info window. If you add an info window then click it, the text is updated. Here the code which works (code tested)

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private TextView test_fr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);

        test_fr = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_fr);
        GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        test_fr.setText("test");

        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(
                new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                        test_fr.setText("CHANGE THE CONTENT");
                        Toast.makeText(MyActivity.this, "Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });

        // Add marker with info window
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(47.3167, 5.0167))
                .title("Hello France")
        );
    }

}
```

Enjoy !